# How do I remove the social widgets at the bottom of Projects in starter-academic hugo pages?

Tags: icons, hugo, blogdown, wowchemy

I have a wowchemy starter-academic website that I serve with blogdown via RStudio. I customized it and it works fine, but there is one thing I can't figure out how to change.
At the bottom of each Project page (which I have renamed to Resources) but before the footer, there a bunch of social network icons (Twitter, LinkedIn etc. - see screenshot with icons circled in red) that I want to delete. I went through all the config files, the layouts/partial but I can't figure where these are specified or where they could be modified. Any hints would be appreciated. I'm also attaching my folder structure, maybe that helps. The site can be found here: https://sauderset.github.io/

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using software built by George Cushen. If you want support on this, you can best ask him directly at https://georgecushen.com. He offers paid support through a Discord(?) forum.

Answer (score 0):

> I went through all the config files

What do you want to find in your config files? I think that you need just to change this setting to false in params.yml

`sharing: true`